# setmargin does not work in relative layout in android

Tags: android, margin, android-relativelayout

I have created 2 buttons in a relative layout programmatically. I want no margin space between the buttons and tried to achieve this by using 'setmargin' but failed. Below is the code.

```
//creating the relative layout
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);   
//creating buttons
    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    button1.setId(R.id.button1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            SCR_W/2,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);//SCR_W is the device screenwidth
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    button1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    relativeLayout.addView(button1);  

    Button button2 = new Button(this);
    button2.setId(R.id.button2);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            SCR_W/2,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, button1.getId());
    params2.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    button2.setLayoutParams(params2);
    relativeLayout.addView(button2);

//setting the relative layout as the contentview
     setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, and works ok to me,

The two buttons are at distance 0. To check it, simply set different color to each button, and you will see that they are together.

```
button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the relative layout to `wrap_content`..

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try something like this, it will work -:

```
 params1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, -5);
 params2.setMargins(0, -5, 0, 0);
```